# How to get the url of all video files stored in photo library with photokit

Tags: ios, swift, url, video, photokit

I have found a lot of solutions, but all of them are implemented with ALAssetLibrary, But the assetlibrary will be depreciated in iOS 9, I do not know how to get video files in photo library, and get their url and thumbnail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could play around with the [sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014575-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) code Apple provides for photo kit

Code would be something like

```
PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) -> Void in
            let allVidOptions = PHFetchOptions()
            allVidOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.Video.rawValue)
            allVidOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]
            let allVids = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithOptions(allVidOptions)
            for index in 0..<allVids.count {
                //fetch Asset here
                print(allVids[index])
            }

        }
```

Comment: This is definitely the way to go. Will note that the user tagged `swift` with his question though so it might be helpful to update your answer for swift.

Comment: thanks. i am currently testing the code, and will update with a proper swift example.

Answer (score 3):

**You can also use the function fetchAssets with media type**

**Video**

```
let videosArray = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: nil)
```

**Images**

```
let imagesArray = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: nil)
```